# jQuery insert element without parent resize

Tags: jquery, css, dom

i have following structure:

```
<td>
  <input name="foo" size="45"/>
</td>
```

And i want to dynamically insert image after that and then position it **inside input**, like this:

```
$j('<img class="icon-ketchup" style="display: none; position: relative; right: 35px; top: 7px;" src="http://localhost:82/pod/plugin_assets/webshop/images/icons/cross.png" />').show().insertAfter($j('input'));
```

My `td` is the same size as `input`, and I don't want to resize the `td` element. How is this possible to achieve ?

Comment: Why don't you use `overflow:hidden;` for the `td`? Do you want to show  full size of images?

Comment: You can just set the width attribute of the image to the size of the td. It will rescale it proportionally if you don't set the height attribute.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to show an image on top of an input field?

Comment: Image displays only after client side validation fails. I want to bind to that image, so after user mouseover it shows form validation errors in a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to position it with absolute.  Javascript is not needed, but can still be used it you want.  See http://jsfiddle.net/C7trn/

HTML

```
<td style="position: relative; border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px;">
<input name="foo" size="45"/>
<img class="icon-ketchup" style="position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 7px;" src="http://localhost:82/pod/plugin_assets/webshop/images/icons/cross.png" />
</td>​
```

The key is making the TD `position: relative;` and then having the image `position: absolute`.  This will make the image absolutely positioned relative to the `td`.

Comment: I cannot use background because i need an mouseover event on my image.

Comment: Updated with solution.  I added border and padding to the TD to make it easier to see, you can get rid of that.

Comment: It seems to work, is there any possibility that relative inside my table will destroy sth ?

Comment: Position relative without any offsets is the same as the default static.  Unless you have anything else in the td that expected a different non-static parent to be relative to.